# Loop to convert to date for multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b"), date1 = c("06/10/2003", "2006-05-12"), date2 = c("2003-07-15", "10/01/2010"))

id  date1       date2
a   06/10/2003  2003-07-15
b   2006-05-12  10/01/2010
```

I would like to convert these characters to dates. So far, I have been able to do it one column at a time with the following code:

```
df$new_date <- as.Date(df$date1, format =  "%m/%d/%Y")
df$new_date2 <- as.Date(df$date1, format =  "%Y-%m-%d") 
df <- df %>%
  mutate(date1 = coalesce(new_date,new_date2))
```

But I have a bunch of columns, is there a way to loop this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a function from **`lubridate`**, along with `across` within `mutate`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with("date"), 
                  ~lubridate::parse_date_time(.,orders = c("mdy", "ymd"))))

#   id      date1      date2
# 1  a 2003-06-10 2003-07-15
# 2  b 2006-05-12 2010-10-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reshape the data frame using `pivot_longer` so all of the dates are in one column, then use a vectorized condition to address each of the formatting variations in turn, then use `pivot_wider` to return the data frame to its original shape.

```
library(tidyverse)

pivot_longer(df, cols = c("date1", "date2")) %>%
    mutate(
        value = case_when(
            grepl("-", value) ~ as.Date(value, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
            grepl("/", value) ~ as.Date(value, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
            )
    ) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value")

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  id    date1      date2     
  <chr> <date>     <date>    
1 a     2003-06-10 2003-07-15
2 b     2006-05-12 2010-10-01
```